# Why do type.getConstructor take a type array as inparameter?

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor

I am currently trying to learn reflection and have seen some examples where GetConstructor is used, i guess that it is one of the basic functions i need to understand, to be able to start work with reflection. I think that I understand what the code does and how I would use it.

Code example from msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h.aspx

```
types[0] = typeof(int);
// Get the constructor that takes an integer as a parameter.
ConstructorInfo constructorInfoObj = myType.GetConstructor(types);
```

The only problem I have with the code, is that i can't understand why I need to create a dummy Type Array to be able to use the GetConstructor method(except from “the method is constructed in that way”). In my mind, the logical inparameter would be an integer containing the index of the constructor I am trying to get by reflection. If a reason exists, can someone explain why a type array is used as inparameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs a `Type[]` to search for `constructor` with specific signature.

The `array represent the order of Parameter` Type accepted in the `Constructor`

As per the example given on MSDN

```
public class MyClass1
  {
      public MyClass1(){}
      public MyClass1(int i){}
  }
```

if you has passed something like

```
Type[] types = new Type[1];
types[0] = typeof (long);

ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = typeof (MyClass1).GetConstructor(types);
```

`constructorInfo` would have been `null`, as no `constructor` exists that takes `long` as argument

Answer (score 4):

Constructors are searched by the signature, i.e. by the ordered list of parameter types. That's why you need to pass an array of constructor parameter types. This is quite logical, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Because a constructor can have zero or more parameters.  The list of types tells reflection *which* constructor to get.

Answer (score 1):

> [..] i can't understand why I need to create a dummy Type Array to be
>   able to use the GetConstructor method(except from “the method is
>   constructed in that way”)

Often, reflection solves problems like "create an object from a type that is known to have a constructor that takes an int, then a string, then a double." With this in mind, it makes sense that an array of parameter-types is provided as the input. Since you're looking for a *single* constructor from a type that potentially has several, how else could you hope to disambiguate?

> In my mind, the logical in parameter would be an integer containing
>   the index of the constructor I am trying to get by reflection.

What do you expect this index to represent? Members are not guaranteed to be ordered by the reflection API in the same order that they were declared in the source programming language.
In any case, it looks like you want an array of constructors that you can enumerate / index into. [`Type.GetConstructors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e687hf0d.aspx) will help with this.